# How can I create a fixed header and a 100% inner container?

Tags: css, layout, css-tables

I'm trying to create a flexible layout for a mobile web app and i'm struggling to make this work with CSS tables. Currently i'm using the old flexbox but I wanted to try and replicate it with CSS tables. I would like to have a fixed height header with a content container that is always 100% tall.

Where am I going wrong? Also would the flex-box be a better option? (albeit in flux)

```
    -----------------------------
    |          .header          |
    -----------------------------
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |      .inner-container     |
    |                           |
    |                           |
    -----------------------------
```

.

I have created a (failing) [css table example](http://jsfiddle.net/BpgSW/)
and also a working [flex box example](http://jsfiddle.net/7cMJY/)

.

```
<div class='wrap'>    
    <div class='header'></div>
    <div class='inner-container'></div>
</div>



.wrap {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.header {
    display: table-cell;
    background: red;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're displaying `.header` and `.inner-container` as table cells, so they'll be next to each other rather than stacked.

The main issue though is that what you're trying to do is difficult with tables unless you set a pixel hight on `wrap`, because of the way heights are calculated by the browser.

If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHaSc/2/), and change the outer div's height to `1000px` instead of `100%`, you'll notice that you get the right sizing, but you won't with `height: 100%`.

Edit: More explanation of why this happens can be found [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm).

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense with the rows, I completely forgot those... doh! +1 on the extra info link and fiddle, very helpful.